# SyantaxError: Unexpected token '<' ESMLoader.moduleStrategy ....how I fix it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I face this issue while running my react App.js file on vsCode. How do I fix it?
The error is-->

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:115:18) at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:289:14) at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: link the app js as well as the repo link or a codesandbox link if possible

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this issue, I had a different error but with exactly the same stack trace.
I got this error while using Laravel with Inertia + Svelte and Tailwind, the error occured in my app.css after cloning the repository from another machine.
My error looked like this:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [postcss] Unexpected end of input

    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21
```

In my case I managed to fix it by deleting the node modules folder and running npm install.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```